# How to create Invoice via Code

Tags: cloud, erp, acumatica

I am doing some customization, I need to create invoice/memo via code. Just like create invoice/memos ( Screen). Can you give me some suggestion about this case?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create instance of graph ARInvoiceEntry

var arEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance();

or

```
 var arEntry = PXGraph.CreateInstance(typeof(ARInvoiceEntry )); ).
```

2. Creaate invoice. For example

ARInvoice invoice = new ARInvoice();

3. Set values of Invoice.
4. Call insert method of arEntry:

arEntry.Document.Insert(invoice);

5. Call

   arEntry.Persist();

Thats it. Keep in mind, that in order to create DAC objects and persist them in db, you need to use separated graph. You can't in any graph to create and Persist any object you like.

Comment: For another example of usage you can look into graph PMBillEngine, method Bill. It creates ARInvoice, generates and binds ARTrans to invoice and persists it invoice and artrans into db. I suspect it does something else, but it was out of scope of my task

Comment: DMSpro.DangHuynh did it help?

Comment: I got another problem when call persist function. I got error "Revision ID is not empty". Can you have me about this error?

Comment: I propose you to create separated question with description of your code